# HTML and JS player with a playlist plays only one music

Tags: javascript, html

is my first time here. :)

I have a music player with a playlist in HTML5 e JS on my customer web site.

It  works with a array, but only one music play and repeat on a loop. The others music doesn't play.

The Code:

JavaScript

```
unu_music = {
    // music play
    m_play: function () {
        $('.btn-play').click(function () {
            $('.btn-play').hide();
            $('.btn-pause').show();
            $("#music")[0].play();
        });
    },
    // music pause
    m_pause: function () {
        $('.btn-pause').click(function () {
            $('.btn-pause').hide();
            $('.btn-play').show();
            $("#music")[0].pause();
        });
    },
    // music stop
    m_stop: function () {
        $('.btn-stop').click(function () {
            // action stop
            $("#music")[0].pause();
            $("#music")[0].currentTime = 0;
            // button play show
            $('.btn-pause').hide();
            $('.btn-play').show();
            // button sound show
            $('.btn-sound-mute').hide();
            $('.btn-sound').show();
            $("#music")[0].volume += 1;
        });
    },
    // music sound
    m_sound: function () {
        $('.btn-sound-mute').click(function () {
            $('.btn-sound-mute').hide();
            $('.btn-sound').show();
            $("#music")[0].volume += 1;
        });
    },
    // music mute
    m_mute: function () {
        $('.btn-sound').click(function () {
            $('.btn-sound').hide();
            $('.btn-sound-mute').show();
            $("#music")[0].volume -= 1;
        });
    },
    // playlist
    m_playlist: function () {
        var arr, aux = 1, mls = [],
            unuPlayList = [
                {
                    mp3: '../music/music-01.mp3',
                    ogg: '../music/music-01.ogg',
                    duration: '2:52'
                },
                {
                    mp3: '../music/music-02.mp3',
                    ogg: '../music/music-02.ogg',
                    duration: '4:05'
                },
                {
                    mp3: '../music/music-03.mp3',
                    ogg: '../music/music-03.ogg',
                    duration: '4:58'
                }
            ];

        $('audio').html('<source src=' + unuPlayList[aux].ogg + ' type="audio/ogg">');

        for (var i = 0; i < unuPlayList.length; i++) {
            arr = unuPlayList[i].duration.split(':');
            mls[i] = ((((arr[0] * 60) * 1000) + (arr[1] * 1000)) - 70000);
        }

        setInterval(function () {
            if (aux != -1) {
                $('audio').html('<source src=' + unuPlayList[aux].ogg + ' type="audio/ogg">');
                aux++;
            }

            if (aux == unuPlayList.length)
                aux = 0;

        }, mls[aux]);
    }
};
```

HTML

```
 <audio id="music" autoplay loop>

    </audio>
```

How Can I resolve this bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your music player plugin name?

Comment: this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423040/html5-play-audio-loop-4x-then-stop) may be helful for you

Comment: @RassolGhafari , this is  not a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a plugin like this :
here's a link of podsnack [click here to go to podsnack](http://www.podsnack.com/)!