# How do I stop my html5 audio playlist from looping?

Tags: javascript

I've set up a play list for our website.  I finally got the auto play to stop but now I can't stop each track from looping.  The last song in the list actually stops after it is played but the rest keep going and going.  Here is the Javascript being used.  Am I missing something?

```
</style> <script>
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('#audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .20;
    audio[0].play();
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
</script>
```

Comment: similar- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423040/html5-play-audio-loop-4x-then-stop

Comment: how do you try to stop it?