# Javascript audio loop

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3, html5-audio

I want to play an audio in background 3 times and after 3 times the audio will stop automaticlly.
I've tried this code and it did not work.
HTML CODE:

```
<audio id='beep' controls>
<source src="beep-02.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var count = 1
document.getElementById('beep').addEventListener('ended', function(){
   this.currentTime = 0;
   if(count <= 3){
      this.play();
   }
   count++;
}, false);
```

Thanks.

Comment: [This is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423040/html5-play-audio-loop-4x-then-stop).

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what did it do?

Comment: It may certainly be a duplicate, but the accepted answer there is suspicious. Unless you really can't rely on the `ended` event I don't think you want to have to rely on a `setInterval or setTimeout` to happen to match the duration of the audio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 play audio loop 4x then stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423040/html5-play-audio-loop-4x-then-stop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using onended:
Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp or it could be you need to increment your count before you call play() again

```
var count = 1;
var audio = document.getElementById('beep');
audio.onended = function() {
    if(count <= 3){
      count++;
      this.play();
   }
};
```

Comment: There should be no functional difference between adding a listener for the `ended` event or setting an explicit handler for `onended`…

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if your using Event listener i think you have to call bind() in order to use 'this' inside of the function? such as:     audio.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        this.handle_keydown(e);
    }.bind(this), false);
reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996263/javascript-scope-addeventlistener-and-this

Comment: No, the context of the function, `this, will be set to the event's `currentTarget` In this case, `this` will be the audio element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener "When attaching a handler function to an element using addEventListener(), the value of this inside the handler is a reference to the element. It is the same as the value of the currentTarget property of the event argument that is passed to the handler."

Comment: Reading the reference, it seems that the function would need to be part of the element and not set as a new (anonymous) function "If an event attribute (e.g., onclick) is specified on an element in the HTML source, the JavaScript code in the attribute value is effectively wrapped in a handler function that binds the value of this in a manner consistent with the use of addEventListener()" But maybe i read it wrong... I'll have to give it a test sometime

Comment: I've attached an example jsfiddle to my answer below http://jsfiddle.net/jorw3yfn/ So I'm not being misconstrued; yes, I think both approaches will work fine and are generally equivalent. But I don't think the "problem" was that the author was using addEventListner versus setting onended. i.e. The answer here doesn't actually explain how this fixed anything. Otherwise, there are pros and cons to both approaches.

Comment: Good to know, I agree, I am unsure if it was where he had his count? Else i would update my answer. I do like the direction you went with your answer though. Either way, the issue seems resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var count = 0;
document.getElementById('beep').addEventListener('ended', function(){
   if(count <= 3){
      this.play();
      count++;
   }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you do want to to play in the background you'll need to add an `autoplay` attribute as well.

```
<audio id='beep' controls autoplay>
  <source src="beep-02.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

2) This should work pretty much as you authored but in some browsers may require resetting the playhead if you will: `this.currentTime = 0`

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var count = 0
document.getElementById('beep').addEventListener('ended', function(){
  count++;
  if (count < 3) {
    this.currentTime = 0; // may be needed in some browsers to reset
    this.play();
  }
}, false);
```

For the record I had previously proposed using the `loop` attribute and simply stopping after `ended` fired 3 times, but when I tested it, `loop` prevents `ended` from ever firing.

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/jorw3yfn/

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // the audio loop trick is "alertCount" value, try playing around with it
  var alarmData = {
    "alertCount": 3,
    "trigger": [{
        "id": 47,
        "status": "active",
        "create_uid": 1,
        "create_date": "2018-04-19 01:38:39.59",
        "region": null,
        "acknowledge_by": "Hashmat",
        "write_uid": 1,
        "write_date": "2018-04-23 03:35:04.745",
        "date": "2018-04-19",
        "serial": null,
        "sim": null,
        "acknowledge_date": "2018-04-19",
        "station_id": null,
        "station_alerts": 72,
        "sound_triggered": null
      },
      {
        "id": 48,
        "status": "active",
        "create_uid": 1,
        "create_date": "2018-04-19 01:38:39.59",
        "region": null,
        "acknowledge_by": "Hashmat",
        "write_uid": 1,
        "write_date": "2018-04-23 03:35:04.745",
        "date": "2018-04-19",
        "serial": null,
        "sim": null,
        "acknowledge_date": "2018-04-19",
        "station_id": null,
        "station_alerts": 72,
        "sound_triggered": null
      },
      {
        "id": 49,
        "status": "active",
        "create_uid": 1,
        "create_date": "2018-04-19 01:38:39.59",
        "region": null,
        "acknowledge_by": "Hashmat",
        "write_uid": 1,
        "write_date": "2018-04-23 03:35:04.745",
        "date": "2018-04-19",
        "serial": null,
        "sim": null,
        "acknowledge_date": "2018-04-19",
        "station_id": null,
        "station_alerts": 72,
        "sound_triggered": null
      },
      {
        "id": 50,
        "status": "active",
        "create_uid": 1,
        "create_date": "2018-04-19 01:38:39.59",
        "region": null,
        "acknowledge_by": "Hashmat",
        "write_uid": 1,
        "write_date": "2018-04-23 03:35:04.745",
        "date": "2018-04-19",
        "serial": null,
        "sim": null,
        "acknowledge_date": "2018-04-19",
        "station_id": null,
        "station_alerts": 72,
        "sound_triggered": null
      }
    ]

  };

  var audioElements = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');


  $.each(alarmData.trigger, function(index, alart_value) {


    // update the status
    // once the sounds are played (once for each alarm), then update the status for each alarm triggered
    var countAlert = alarmData.alertCount;



    if (alart_value.sound_triggered == null || alart_value.sound_triggered === false) {

      audioElements[index].play(); // play the alert for first time
      audioElements[index].onended = function() { // once finished, then play it according the number of alerts from backend(for jsfiddle purpose we use local data source)
        if (index < --countAlert) {
          this.play();
        }
      };
    }



  }); // close foreach loop for alertData.trigger

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls id="audio">
    <source src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1599&type=mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Note: Ignore the error