# Audio autoplay repeating unlimited times html5

Tags: php, html, html5-audio

I have used a audio autoplay system in php echo. It works. But repeating it again and again. I want to make it that it will repeat only one time. How can I solve it.

```
if ($rowcount >= '1'){
    echo '
    <audio autoplay>
    <source src="notification_sound.mp3">
    </audio>';
}
```

Comment: Did you putted `if` in loop?

Comment: yes, I need to put it into if loop

Comment: So it write in html any time loop run. You should write it one time

Comment: can u help me in this case

Comment: Define variable like `$audioAdd = false` and check it in condition like `if ($rowcount >= '1' && !$audioAdd){..` and in end of `if` write `$audioAdd = true`

Comment: not working I have diid this

Comment: Like https://3v4l.org/Y6IKG

Comment: So, you need an audio file to play for 2 times right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930534/javascript-audio-loop/34930786#34930786

Comment: Try `$rowcount >= 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sound = document.getElementById('id_given_audio_tag');
setTimeout(function(){
    sound.play();

    setTimeout(function(){
        sound.pause();
        sound.currentTime = 0;
    }, time_in_sec_it_takes_sound_to_play+1000);
}, time_in_sec_it_takes_the_sound_to_play);
```

hope it works