# Change source code of web page so that it repay an audio automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML/Javascript. I opened a dictionary in the web browser using google chrome. I then went to the source code by right click on the web-page and select inspection.  I located the part of HTML code that has the audio that I want to replay. So now I want to add more code so that I can have a small box next to the audio play button to input the number of times the audio should play in a loop.

I found that I could add

```
<video controls loop>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

to replay a video.  I don't know where to add the codes. Here is the screenshot of the dictionary web:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to change it for all visitors to larousse.fr or for you locally?

Comment: It is locally, for myself, I want to learn french.

Comment: The `href` attribute points to an mp3 file, where the TTS has been recorded. This website has some js that will play this file, so you could use it too, e.g by typing `let played = 0;
let times = 10;
const playAgain = () => soundManager.play($0.href, {url: $0.href, onload:e=>{if(played++ < times) playAgain();}});
playAgain();` in your console when you do select the `<a>` element, or you could simply navigate to this url and have access to the mp3.

Comment: But note that this is just TextToSpeech, so you may also just choose your preferred French voice TTS and do it yourself, preferably in a full sentence, because e.g here as a French speaker, I can tell you that this particular audio is a very bad example on how to pronounce the entering "b". The best to learn a language is probably to listen to real humans' speaking.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click that code then select `Edit as HTML` then you can add/edit whatever code you want to add/edit on that line.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the actual source code of this website? What you highlighted in the developer tools is not an audio tag but a link tag. There might be JavaScript running somewhere that plays audio when the user clicks on the link, but that code is not visible in your screenshot. This makes your question very hard to answer.

In theory, though, you can probably count how many times a user is listening to the audio file by registering clicks on the link with the onclick event listener.

Mozilla Developer Network has great documentation, with an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Hope it helps!

Comment: Mh. I just realized I misunderstood your question. I'm not exactly sure how you can go about setting the number of times the audio can be played before ending the loop in this particular case. If you can use jQuery, I think that the answer to that question can be the solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423040/html5-play-audio-loop-4x-then-stop.